# Visual C++ 2015 - attempting to reference a deleted function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I am getting two errors when compiling code with VC++ 2015 that I did not get with VC++ 2013.  Here are the two snippets:

```
CArray<CQualifiedFolderObject*, CQualifiedFolderObject*> CQualifiedFolderObject::mQualifiedFolders =
         CArray<CQualifiedFolderObject*, CQualifiedFolderObject*>()
```

and

```
sProfileArray COesInterface::g_arrProfiles[] = {
    {FALSE, },
    {FALSE, },
    {FALSE, },
    {FALSE, },
    {FALSE, CStringArray()},    
};
```

In both cases I get a C2280 *"attempting to reference a deleted function"* error.  In the first case it is for the `CArray` and in the second case it is for the `CStringArray`.

I am relatively new to C++.  I'd like to understand why this compiles in 2013 and not 2015, and what I can do to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

check the definition of the class , this error means that either your class has defined the custom destruct-or or one of the function that changes the default generation of the other function.

For example : if you declare and define destruct-or , you will not get default copy constructor.

there are six of them , check the rule or default all of them.

syntax below : if you try to copy it will produce same error as above.

```
struct noncopyable
{
  noncopyable() =default;
  noncopyable(const noncopyable&) =delete;
  noncopyable& operator=(const noncopyable&) =delete;
};
```